# PN TRIANGLES is Bezier Triangles right?

Tags: directx11

JUst wondering the term pn triangles is the same thing as saying bezier triangle patch??/

Comment: The PN triangles method involves theoretical triangular Bezier patches, but saying they are the "same thing" is oversimplified.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, in this context:

- "patch" generally refers to a surface generated by control points, rather than vertices
- "Bezier" generally refers to applying the Bernstein polynomial of an arbitrary degree to said surface
- "triangle" (probably) refers to the fact that the theoretical, smooth, surface is degenerated into real, flat, triangles for rendering. (A rectangular Bezier surface is in the quad domain, not triangle)

A *Bezier Triangle* is a special-case, bi-quadratic surface (the patch is a triangle), where a "bezier triangle patch" probably refers to a bi-cubic surface (the patch is a rectangle) rendered using triangles.

The main idea behind "PN triangles" is to produce better shading, using the same input data, faster, and without adding anything extraordinary to the graphics pipeline. The method uses Bezier Triangles which are, mathematically, easier to subdivide. It also "Beziers" the normals instead of lerping and contains optimizations to reduce creasing/cracking artifacts while still maintaining performance on less-capable hardware. The input PN triangles (lowest-LOD version of the geometry) render about as fast as normal triangles, take the same amount of space to store, and the same amount of time to upload to the GPU.

So, in essence, the algorithm just packs a superior description of the geometry into the same footprint that "normal triangles" have.

This image was extracted from [this pdf](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/SurfLab/papers/00ati.pdf), which is worth a read. The top shows a Bezier patch with lerp'ed normals and the bottom shows the PN algorithm's "Bezier'ed" normals. Subdivided PN triangles maintain more-accurate normals than their "normal" counterparts.

[image]

From [Bézier surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface):

> A Bézier patch of degree (m, n) may be constructed out of two Bézier triangles of degree m+n, or out of a single Bézier triangle of degree m + n, with the input domain as a square instead of as a triangle.
>
> A Bézier triangle of degree m may also be constructed out of a Bézier surface of degree (m, m), with the control points so that one edge is squashed to a point, or with the input domain as a triangle instead of as a square.

Also [Bézier triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_triangle).